# Animating Quartz 2d

Tags: ios, animation, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to animate a bezier spline that is changing it's shape. The tutorials I am fining are for doing block or key frame animations. I want to calculate the shape of the curve and draw it every frame that it changes.

Can some point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually calculate it for every frame then you should read [this article about custom animations](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2012/02/animating-pie-slices-using-a-custom-calayer/).

It will also show how you in many cases can do it without having to do the calculations for every frame.